# Parsing URL in cocoa

Tags: regex, cocoa, parsing, url

The URL is: `http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=244832666b8168a3mna06f03f5324789a8022455245532b032375f193ceab923&expires_in=86400&user_id=191742`

How to parse it in Cocoa and get the `access_token` and `user_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `-fragment` method of `NSURL` which returns the string after `#`.

Here's what is use. It's very basic and does not support entities (like `&amp;`), it just splits the string by `&` and then by `=`.

```
@interface NSURL (SYBasicKeyValueParsing)
- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfString:(NSString *)string;
- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfFragment;
- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfQuery;
@end

@implementation NSURL (SYBasicKeyValueParsing)

- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!string) return nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSString *pair in [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
        NSArray *keyAndValue = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if ([keyAndValue count] == 2) {
            [result setObject:[keyAndValue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[keyAndValue objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }
    return [[result copy] autorelease];
}

- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfFragment
{
    return [self sy_keysAndValuesOfString:[self fragment]];
}

- (NSDictionary *)sy_keysAndValuesOfQuery
{
    return [self sy_keysAndValuesOfString:[self query]];
}

@end
```

So `sy_keysAndValuesOfFragment` of your URL will result in this:

```
{
    "access_token" = 244832666b8168a3mna06f03f5324789a8022455245532b032375f193ceab923;
    "expires_in" = 86400;
    "user_id" = 191742;
}
```

Comment: +1, just don't forget to URL-decode the keys and values using `-[NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`

Comment: @DaveDeLong Thanks for the remark! I really forgot about that, but since I use the parser in the situation just like the OP's one ([_a-z0-9]=[_a-z0-9]), the encoding wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class for parsing URLs: [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If this is not enough, you can get the parameters using [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method of NSString class.